# migrate magento database to another serve

Tags: mysql-config

My magento is having very poor performance, at the moment both web and database  are stored on the same VM, hence I would like to separate the database to a dedicated server.

This is the first time I am doing this (separating a database to a different server) so I am seeking for advices/suggestions. I have been searching in Google and stackexchange for some guidance without success.

So far this is my plan:

1. Create new server and install MySQL
2. Stop web server
3. Migrate the database to the new server running mysqldump
4. Create new user mysql login and grant full permission/access to the migrated database.
5. Change the connection on the webserver to point to the new machine on /app/etc/local.xml file.

**NOTE:** both servers will be on the same network.

Is everything? Any other advice/suggestion from the magento gurus?

Answer (score 0):

That seems pretty good. I'd also maybe look at some caching for the magento site as well such as [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), [Lesti_Fpc](https://gordonlesti.com/projects/lestifpc/%20%22Lesti_Fpc), Varnish Caching.